# Couchbase lite ios retrieve documents

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase-lite

How can I retrieve all documents with key containing a certain string? I know how to retrieve one document if I have it key using:

```
let doc = database.documentWithID(myDocID)
```

but if I want all documents where the key contains the string "key" for example is there an easy way to do it or do I have to create view and queries?

Thanks.

Comment: the only way to do it is with views and queries.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out later.

Comment: you should add your edit as an answer instead

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it (with views and queries); I have added a field type and add in it the specification:

```
    let view = db?.viewNamed("list") 
    if view?.mapBlock == nil {
        view?.setMapBlock({ (doc, emit) in
            if let type: String = doc["type"] as? String, let name = doc["name"], let overview = doc["overview"], type == "task" {
                emit(name, nil)
            }
        }, version: "1.0")
    }
    liveQuery = view?.createQuery().asLive()
```